# Add Custom Form to Installer

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have C# application and I need to Create Installer. My requirement is when installer begin to run that will **pop-up a window**, In that Window we have to provide Location of access Db and user name and password. Then these Inputs will Stored in **app.config** file.

can some one give a solution..?

Comment: What are you using to create the installer? WiX?

Comment: I use visulal Studio 2010.